# Cloud Functions retrieve List from Firebase Database

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm triggering a Cloud Function using Http Request.
The issue is to retrieve the entire List of Objects I have, without an event to then loop through them.
The List is under the **account/userId** Node.

Here is what I use but I get nothing:

```
return admin.database().ref('/account/' + userId).once('value').then(function (snap) {
        let data = snap.val();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your database structure it is a bit difficult to write an answer and be 100% sure it is a correct one, but the following should do the trick:

```
return admin.database().ref('/account/' + userId).once('value').then(function (snap)
    snap.forEach(function(child) {
        const childKey = child.key;  // <- here you get the key of each child of the '/account/' + userId node
        console.log(childKey);
        const childVal = child.val(); // <- and here you get the values of these children as JavaScript objects
        console.log(childVal);  
    });
});
```

In case this is not exactly what you are looking for, please update you Question with your database structure and the entire code of your Cloud Function.